# IP Routing Issues OpenVpn

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, ip

I have two servers in the same datacentre, running Ubuntu 16

Server A: 10.12.96.5
Server B: 10.12.96.4

Server A, is running OPENVPN Server.

When I connect to server A using SSH, I can PING server B.

When I connect from my client PC to server A using OpenVPN, I can ping server A using both it's OpenVPN IP (10.8.0.1), and it's private IP (10.12.96.5).

The problem is: I can't ping server B (10.12.96.4) from my client PC

Client-to-client communication is enabled, on OpenVPN.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a 10.12.96.0/24 route over the client's tun device. You can manually add it on the client side: "user@client:~$sudo ip route add 10.12.96.0/24 via (presumably 10.8.0.5 if you have the defaults) dev tun0". Or you can push a route from the server's config: push "route 10.12.96.0 255.255.255.0"

Comment: The other possibility is the ping request is reaching server B, but server B doesn't know how to route the response back to the client. If that's the case, you can add a route on Server B to route whatever client's local subnet is back over Server A's tun device. Or you could SNAT client's vpn traffic to Server A when it leave's server A.

Comment: Here's the routing:

Server A: https://prnt.sc/kbyilr
Server B: https://prnt.sc/kbyi9b

Comment: So does server B have a route back to client? Edit: If you are just pinging Server B from the client with ping -c 2 10.12.96.4 then the source address is probably not the client's tun address.

Comment: You could force the client to use its tun address "ping -c 2 -I 10.8.0.6 10.12.96.4" and replace 10.8.0.6 with whatever the address of client's tun device happens to be.

Comment: server b, has a route back to server a.
from server B, i can't ping the client.
from server A, i can ping the client
from server B, i can ping server A using the Openvpn IP (10.8.0.1)

Comment: What happens when you "ping -c 2 -I (address of client's tun device) 10.12.96.4" from the client machine?

Comment: ping -c 2 10.12.96.4 works on Server B, and Server A.  The client pc is running Windows

Comment: You ran "ping -c 2 10.12.96.4" on Server B? That's server B's own address, of course that works. What happens when you run: "ping -c 2 -I (address of client's tun device) 10.12.96.4" from the client machine?

Comment: I ran "ping -S 10.8.0.2 10.12.96.5" from the client machine (windows, pinging server a), and I received a response.

when I ran "ping -S 10.8.0.2 10.12.96.4" from the client machine (windows, pinging server b); the request timed out.

Comment: Do you have "ip forwarding" enabled on Server A? In /etc/sysctl.conf, is "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" commented?

Comment: IP forwarding is enabled on both server A, and Server B
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Comment: Can you ping Server B from your client machine while running tcpdump on Server B to see if the request is even reaching Server B?

Comment: @cburn11 that was great advice!  I learned a lot!  I had to tcpdump 'tun0'  i ran the following command on `tcpdump -i 'tun0' | grep 'ICMP`.  the error is : UDP port SNMP unreachable  https://imgur.com/a/8eX7qJv

Comment: Server B also has a tun device? You mean server B is also connected to Server A's openvpn's instance?

Comment: server B has no tun device.  Server A has a tun device.  Server B has tun route to Server A because it responds to pings through the tun.

When pinging, from the client Server A (openvpn server), dropped the frame 'udp port snmp unreachable'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to ping another device (or have any sort of communication between them) you need a route from your PC to Server B and a route from Server B to your PC.

In the case that means

- PC to Server B:

  - route on your PC to Server B points to Server A
  - route on Server A to Server B points to Server B
- Server B to PC

  - route on Server B to your PC points to Server A
  - route on Server A to your PC points to your PC

Each of these steps must be correct, otherwise your packets will be lost somewhere.

The program `tcpdump` can show you at each step whether your packets arrive or not.